# Jquery add table row after the row which calling the jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a `table`.

```
<table id="servers" ...>
...
{section name=i loop=$ownsites}
<tr id="site_id_{$ownsites[i].id}">
...
<td>{$ownsites[i].phone}</td>
<td class="icon"><a id="{$ownsites[i].id}" onClick="return makedeleterow(this.getAttribute('id'));" ...></a></td>
</tr>       
{/section}
<tbody>
</table>
```

And this JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makedeleterow(id)
    {
        $('#delete').remove();
        $('#servers').append($(document.createElement("tr")).attr({id: "delete"}));
        $('#delete').append($(document.createElement("td")).attr({colspan: "9", id: "deleter"}));
        $('#deleter').text('Biztosan törölni szeretnéd ezt a weblapod?');
        $('#deleter').append($(document.createElement("input")).attr({type: "submit", id: id, onClick: "return truedeleterow(this.getAttribute('id'))"}));
        $('#deleter').append($(document.createElement("input")).attr({type: "hidden", name: "website_del", value: id}));
    }
</script>
```

It's working fine, it makes a `tr` after the `table`'s last `tr` and puts the info to it, and the delete function also works fine.

But I'd like to make this append ***AFTER*** the `tr` (with `td` `class="icon"`) which is calling the script. How can I do this?

Comment: i think I'm not following you. put use .next() or next('tr') i guess. PS: and you don't have to reselect you elements more then once. you can replace $(document.createElement('tr')) by $('</tr>').attr('id', 'delete')

Comment: Yes, @meo. Instead of $("#deleter") lots of times, just do var deleter = $("#deleter"); then use the variable reference each time.

Comment: f i do this with `$('#site_id_'+id).after().append($(document.createElement("tr")).attr({id: "delete"}));` or with `next()` it will append inside the `tr` after the `td class="icon"`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the .after() function in jQuery to append some content after another element.

So instead of

```
$("servers").append( ... );
```

you would use

```
$("#" + id + ).closest( "tr" ).after( ... );
```

or you could also use

```
$( ... ).insertAfter( $("#" + id ).closest( "tr" ) );
```

which is essentially equivalent.

See http://api.jquery.com/after/ for full details.

Comment: `$('#site_id_'+id).after().append('<tr id="delete"></tr>');` Still not work. Any other idea?

Comment: I think you need to put your <tr id...> in the after() and leave off the append().

Comment: Yeah, add the content as the argument of the after method, there is no need for the append method.

Something like: 
    var newTr = $("<tr id="delete"></tr>"); $('#site_id_'+id).after( newTr ); newTr.append( someChildOfTr ).append( someOtherChildOfTr );

Answer (score 3):

try `.prepend()` instead of `.append()`

Answer (score 1):

interst tr id then onclick="xyz()"

something like this:

```
<tr id=""  onclick="xyz()"><td></td><td></td></tr>
<script>
    function xyz()
    {
    var newrow = "<tr><td>data1</td><td>data1</td></tr>";        
    $("#tr_id").after(newrow);
    }
</script>
```